# how to persist partial view model data during postback in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having partial view Department containing department information. I have Page view of Employee. in Employee view i am using partial view of department to show employees department. My employee model is as below

```
class Employee
{
  public string EmployeeName{get;set};
  public Department EmployeeName{get;set};

}

class Department
{
  public string DepartmentName{get;set};
}
```

I have submit button on employee page view.
When i submit the employee view I am getting Department object as null.
Could you please suggest me how i can get child Department model during postback.
Coltroller code

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Employee2()
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.EmployeeName = "Prashant";
            e.Department = new Department() { DepartmentName = "Phy" };

            return View(e);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Employee2(Employee e)
        {

            return View(e);
        }
```

Views

Department

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Department

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Department</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentName)
        </div>


    </fieldset>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Employee

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Employee
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Employee";
}
<h2>
    Employee</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Home"))
{

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </div>
        @Html.Partial("Department", Model.Department)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="EmployeeSave" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Can the down voter please explain why this question was down voted. It is a good question. Don't just down vote and run away. Let the poster know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try searching first. This question has been asked many times before.

Here is one way to do it:

[mvc partial view post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230045/mvc-partial-view-post)

Summary: wrap each partial in multiple form tags each with their own submit button.

But this one seems more like what you're after:

[Post a form with multiple partial views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608766/post-a-form-with-multiple-partial-views)

Use editortemplates for this instead of partials.

The issue you're having is that when your DepartmentName textbox isn't being named correctly for your controller to read it. Your `POST` would be `EmployeeName=Prashant&DepartmentName=Phy` therefore `Department` is `null`, hence the error.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

Also you changed the Department Model entity name.
 And Department view location in Shared/EditorTemplates.

VIEW:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Employee", "Content"))
{
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.dptEmployeeName.DepartmentName)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Employee</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmployeeName)
        </div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dptEmployeeName.DepartmentName) //This is partial view

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="EmployeeSave" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Employee(Employee e,FormCollection frm)
        {
            var asd = frm["dptEmployeeName.DepartmentName"];

            return View(e);
        }
```